# Error: Overlay manifest:package atribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-34. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Simple Proplem,
hard to solve (i think),

I get this error when i start my main.dart:

```
Error:
    Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-34 value=(com.example.Scanner)
    has a different value=(com.example.Scanner) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:1:70-97
    Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
        flavorName {
            applicationId = "com.example.Scanner"
        }

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId="com.example.Scanner"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
package="com.example.Scanner">
```

I hope someone can help me, otherwise i can´t program at this app anymore :(

After removing `package="com.example.Scanner"`i get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on PCT L29 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(18958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18958): Process: com.example.Scanner, PID: 18958
E/AndroidRuntime(18958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Scanner/your_package_name.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "your_package_name.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.Scanner-qq9H2h8k4abCggEZ2-z28Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.Scanner-qq9H2h8k4abCggEZ2-z28Q==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.Scanner-qq9H2h8k4abCggEZ2-z28Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "your_package_name.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.Scanner-qq9H2h8k4abCggEZ2-z28Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.Scanner-qq9H2h8k4abCggEZ2-z28Q==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.Scanner-qq9H2h8k4abCggEZ2-z28Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1264)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3798)
E/AndroidRuntime(18958):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Remove the package attribute from androidmanifest and check

Comment: i don´t know if this happends, because i removed `package="com.example.Scanner"`, but now i get a new java error :(
I´m very confused. Yesterday i closed the project with a little sharedprefernces error, now i cant start the project anymore.
The java error is in the question above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the work from Midhun MP [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp]:

> Remove the package attribute from androidmanifest and check

i got one error done. Then i got a new java error. I only copied a AndroidManifest.xml from an old project to a new and it worked. This worked for me:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Scanner">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Scanner"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

, but i have no idea what was wrong. I never changed it or so.
Just change `package="com.example.YOURNAME">`
and `android:label="YOURNAME"`

Comment: This is likely the answer you are looking for.  I just ran into this.  Looks like somehow my package was missing a portion of the value.  Not sure how that happened.

For me, my label was something like `awesomeapp` and my package was something like `com.example.awesomeapp` but my app repo and project is actually named `awesomeapp_flutter`.  So I updated my package to be `com.example.awesomeapp_flutter` by adding the `_flutter` at the end, and everything worked fine.  Could be a situation where an android label and project name don't match that creates this failure.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: In most IDEs, you can use the shortcut ctrl-shift-f to search the whole project. It you search for an old package name, you will probably find any references.

Answer (score 22):

[image: This shows the 3 Android files that stores - Android Manifest Files]

I had the same issue, and I changed the package name in 5 locations.

1. `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`
2. `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
3. `android/app/src/profile/AdroidManifest.xml`
4. buildgradle file `defaultConfig { applicationId ""}`
5. MainActivity.java on "package" OR MainActivity.kotlin

After modifying the above files, the Flutter App ran without any issues.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same issue but after going through the following steps I got my point;

Your package name "com.example.com"(in your case It could be different) should be same in 5 locations, like e.g.

1.`android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

2.`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

3.`android/app/src/profile/AdroidManifest.xml`

4.`buildgradle` file `defaultConfig { applicationId ""}`

5.`MainActivity.java` on "package" OR `MainActivity.kotlin`

In my case my package name was com.example.blog_daily. So I rewrite all the packages with the same name at all the points and solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

first make all package name same //to do this search your package name in search bar that show in terminal and fixed them//
then run flutter clean and flutter pub get.
now you can run  flutter run  . I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
I just changed my androidmanifest package name to my project level build.gradle's application id that worked to me. 

//
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="-pasted here-`enter code here`"

from
//
defaultConfig {
        // TOD: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "-copied from here-"
        minSdkVersion`enter code here` 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
```